# Proving that only the linear codes pass parity check

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, coding-theory

An exercise in my book goes as follows:

> Let $C$ be a **binary** $(n,k)$ linear code with parity-check matrix $H$. We know $Hc=0$ for all $c\in C$. Show that $Hw=0$ implies $w\in C$.

---

**My idea:** Let $w\in\mathbb B^n$ be given with $Hw=0$. Define $v\in\mathbb B^k$ by $v=(w_1,w_2,...,w_k)$. Then $u=v^\mathrm TG\in C$ where $G$ is the generator matrix for $C$. Assume for contradiction that $u_{k+i}\neq w_{k+i}$ for some $i\leq n-k$. Then we must have $0=(Hu)_i\neq (Hw)_i$ contradicting that $Hw=0$. It follows that $w=u\in C$.

Is this a reasonable approach and does it make sense?

---

**EDIT:** I work with the definition that $G=[I_k\mid P]$ and $H=[P^\mathrm T\mid I_{(n-k)}]$ so the parity bits are always in the last $n-k$ positions of $v^\mathrm TG$.

Comment: What's your definition of parity-check matrix?

Comment: @GitGud: Good question! I will add a little detail to my post ...

Comment: @GitGud: Does that clarify what I mean?

Comment: Is that really how it was defined? I find that definition problematic. For instance consider $\mathcal \{000,001,110,111\}$. What would $G$ be?

Comment: @GitGud: Depending on the value of $n$ and the corresponding obtainable minimum distance $d$ of encoded words, $G$ would be $G=[I_3\mid P]$ where $P$ is the appropriate parity checks defined by the requirement that $d(u,v)+d(u^\mathrm T P,v^\mathrm T P)\geq d$. The exercise was stated without giving any definitions. Also, my book defines $G$ and $H$ via an example - not via definitions. The definition I gave here is my formulation of what the book examplified ...

Comment: "My book defines $G$ and $H$ via an example - not via definitions." And this why I ended up hating a useful field of mathematics which I could have very easily enjoyed. Good luck with that.

Comment: @GitGud: Actually, I don't mind having to define things for myself. After all definitions are just formulations someone *made up*. But it is very good that you point out if my definition is unclear. I take for granted that potential answerers are familiar with *linear codes* and *parity-checks*. If that is the case and my question is still ambiguous, then that is my fault and should be corrected!

Comment: @GitGud: And first of all: Thank you for taking the time to read through it and ask me to clarify - most appreciated!

Comment: I am familiar with them, I just need to know the definitions to avoid circularity. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the definitions in your question, your proof is fine.
You may want to clarify why $(Hu)_i = 0$. (Hint: It's because $HG^T = 0$.)

---

Note that the definition you gave for a parity check matrix is special case (for [systematic codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_code)) of the general definition:
Typically the parity check matrix of a code $C$ is defined as the generator matrix of the dual code $C^\perp$.
With that definition, we have $c \in C \iff Hc = 0$, of which your exercise is the $\impliedby$ direction.

Answer (score 1):

The general way to proof can be based on:

$ wH^T=0 \Leftrightarrow \exists v \in \mathbb B^k: w=vG \Leftrightarrow  w \in C $

(used here writing vectors as rows).

Really, 
$ C= \lbrace  w \in E_q^n: \exists v \in \mathbb B^k: w=vG  \rbrace . $

Let $ C_1 =\lbrace  w \in E_q^n: wH^t=0 \rbrace . $

We know, that $ C \subseteq C_1 $ (code is linea), $ \mid C_1 \mid =q^k, \mid C \mid =q^k, $ so $ C= C_1 $.

Comment: I suppose you mean $q=2$ here since we are working with $\mathbb B$, right? But how do I now, that the "left null-space" of $H$ (which you denote by $C_1$) has size $2^k$?

Comment: The rows of $ H $ are  linearly independent, so the dimension of null-spase is $ n-k$ and the dimension of $ C $ is $ k $.

Comment: OK, I guess I wanted to avoid using the null-space since the exercise is found on a page in the book where *dimension of a subspace* hasn't been defined yet. But it is fine! I infer from your answer, that it answers NO to the first part of my question. It doesn't answer the second part, though :)

Comment: I do not suppose q = 2 ($ k$ vectors in $\mathbb B^k $ are linearly independent), generally $ q= p^n $. Is not it?

Comment: Sorry, I must admit I have no idea what $q$ and $p$ stands for then. I am only considering binary linear code. Maybe that generalizes to base $q=p^n$ linear codes? I am not that strong in the terminology yet, I can see.